# Inserting into a table of a db and then inserting that new data into another table in the db in the same async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, async-await, supabase

So I am using supabase and I want to allow a user to create partner and that lives in one table called orgs but the ids have a relationship in a partners table. General flow;

[mermaidERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nswIg.png)

I am trying the follow but get an empty array on the partner update.

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: newOrgData, error: newOrgError } = await supabase
      .from('organizations')
      .insert([{ name: partnerOrgName }])
      .select();
      console.log(newOrgData);

      setPartnerOrgName(newOrgData.name);
      setPartnerOrgId(newOrgData.id);
    
    if (newOrgError) {
      throw newOrgError;
    }
  
    const { data: newPartnerData, error: newPartnerError } = await supabase
      .from('partners')
      .insert([{ 
        organization_id: user.organization_id, 
        partner_organization_id: newOrgData.id,
      }])
      .select();
      console.log(newPartnerData);

    if (newPartnerError) {
      throw newPartnerError;
    }
    setIsOpen(false);

    await fetchOrganizations();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

I would expect it to take the user.organizatio_id and insert it and the newOrgData.id and insert it into the appropriate rows on the partners table

Comment: If you're trying to `insert()`, why are you also calling `select()`?

Comment: I am using the ```select()``` to be able to ```console.log``` and see what the data output is. It let me see that I was creating new orgs but not creating new partner relationships. Then as I have tried some different solutions it has helped to see if I broke or fixed it without having to jump over to the db.

Comment: You insert the `partnerOrgName` into the field `name` of the table `organizations`. This operation returns the `newOrgData` object, with fields `id` (generated, I guess) and `name` (the same one you supplied). This works well. Then, you _should_ insert `newOrgData.id` into the field of the table `partners` that references `organizations` (that's the "relationship", the FK). Why do you have two foreign IDs in `partners` (`organization_id` and `partner_organization_id`)? One of them is unnecessary and/or you're mixing their names. Also, what's the role of the variable `user.organization_id`?